# Using NIAttributedLabel in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, nimbus

Problem: Using `NIAttributedLabel` in `UITableViewCell` with Action(tap, navigate)

1. adding a link in label
2. adding label to cell
3. adding cell to model with action tap

Here is the problem, if I touch the label on the link, it actually does not show the link but act the tap action.
But if I add a `UIButton` in `UITableViewCell` in the same way, the action does not happen and the button response when I touch on the button.
So I guess it is the problem with the label.
How can I solve it?

I figured out this finally;

1. adding function to file NIAttributedLabel.m

   ```
   -(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        // never return self. always return the result of [super hitTest..].
        // this takes userInteraction state, enabled, alpha values etc. into account
        UIView *hitResult = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

        // don't check for links if the event was handled by one of the subviews
        if (hitResult != self) {
            return hitResult;
        }

        if (self.explicitLinkLocations || self.detectedlinkLocations) {
            BOOL didHitLink = ([self linkAtPoint:point] != nil);
            if (!didHitLink) {
                // not catch the touch if it didn't hit a link
                return nil;
            }
        }
        return hitResult;
   }
   ```
2. remove all [super touch XXXX] functions in all touchXXX;

then, it works!